# How do I kill a process by its name in Linux?

Tags: linux, process, kill

I have a process with the name `bla`, and I want to kill it by its name.

When I run `ps aux | grep "bla"`, I get 2 entries:

- process `bla` and
- `blablablab`

How do I filter it out?

Comment: Please be more specific and provide the example or the actual terminal scrrenshot.

Answer (score 12):

```
killall bla
```

to force it:

```
killall -9 bla
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [pkill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill), if available.

Comment: +1. man pkill also mentions the pgrep. The tools are part of the same package as top and ps and should be available on pretty much all Linux systems. (Solaris has them too). killall and pidof are not so portable.

Comment: pkill is the most flexible by far. Kills by user, parent process, terminal…

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PID of the process to kill it.

Check out man pages for command kill.

The exact option would be `kill -9 <pid>`

Comment: Do you shut down your computer by holding the power button for X amount of seconds also? Because kill -9 is equally stupid. Please read http://speculation.org/garrick/kill-9.html

Comment: this way you are killing the process by his pid but by this name.

Answer (score 0):

While the killing question has been well answered, you asked how can you avoid getting the process "blabla" when you wanted "bla".  What you want to do is add -w:

```
ps aux | grep -w "bla"
```

Comment: This does not kill it by its name.

Comment: Not intended to kill, I just noticed no one had answered his other question, namely how to find "bla" without finding "blabla".